# Accessing MPS Atlas from Python with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, esri-production-mapping

I'm having trouble finding documentation on accessing MPS Atlas features using python in ArcGIS 10.

I need to be able to modify dataframe manager properties, swap map sheets, etc.

Is it part of arcpy.mapping?

From what I can see, there is no documentation of it on the ESRI Resource Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding was that Production Mapping and MPS Atlas are not available within the Python Environment. When an API or an ArcObjects like exposure of the objects was suggested at previous versions it was raised and rejected. In doing a little research for this Qu

In saying this in Python there is some tools from Production Mapping in Python. have a look at the attached page. Unfortunately it is really only exposing a toolbox but it is Production mapping in python

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010900000016000000.htm